# how to deserialize an instance of "Serialization" without the implementation class on the classpath?

Tags: java, serialization, classloader, classnotfoundexception, unsafe

I'm writing a tool that need to get an instance of `java.io.Serializable` from a byte array.
The difficulty is that the "real" class is not (and cannot be...) on the classpath (I will not explain why here..).
The code below fails on `is.readObject()` with a `ClassNotFoundException` because the implementation class is not on the classpath
Q:
Is is possible to achieve this? by reflection? by using `Unsafe`? by using a sub class of `ClassLoader`? or...?

```
byte[] data = ...
try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));) {
   Object o = ois.readObject();
   Serializable s = (Serializable)o;
}
```

Comment: *Is is possible to achieve this?* Not without the implementation. Yes you could write a `ClassLoader` to load the `class`. But then you're back to needing the class.

Comment: Ditto what Eliott said.  Java serialization sends the data of a class only, not the class itself (not the methods or the definitions of what the data means).  Without the class, you are sunk.

Comment: I would love to know why the downvotes...it is "bad" to ask this kind of question? or induced othere users into error? or give a false anser? I don't think so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is iis possible to achieve this?

No.

> by reflection?

No.

> by using Unsafe?

No.

> by using a sub class of ClassLoader?

Yes but the class loader still has to get the class from somewhere. The RMI codebase feature is a good example.

Comment: I'm working with JEE and the JMS API. In JMS there is a "ObjectMessage" class (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ObjectMessage.html ) that can encapsulate a "serializable" object. You can get this serializable with the getObject() nethod. This method works even if the implementation class is not on the classpath. So i guess I need to decompile an implementation of this API to examine how they do it